# Android studio build apk with transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease error

Tags: android, gradle, android-proguard

When I try to build my project with release build variant, then I receive an error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComBalysvMaterialRipple101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers138Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta116Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics257Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore2310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubKsoichiroAndroidpagecontrol011Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPkmmteViewCircularimageview11Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1312Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItNeokreeMaterialNavigationDrawer133Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesRelease
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
ProGuard, version 5.2.1
Reading input...
Reading program jar [/Users/zsolt/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-android/0.84.2/61e6edd15626bc5278a00593b604274539222a8f/realm-android-0.84.2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/zsolt/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit/converter-gson/2.0.0-beta2/392c3d09e0f5e7087544093cc0cb23bb9c7af5fa/converter-gson-2.0.0-beta2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/zsolt/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime/0.11.91.1/8669cc696e56855d38f0ca876586a9324dad5adc/kotlin-runtime-0.11.91.1.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/Users/zsolt/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okio/okio/1.6.0/98476622f10715998eacf9240d6b479f12c66143/okio-1.6.0.jar] (filtered)
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { void setSuggestionsAdapter(android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete { void setSearchView(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar { void setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$OnMenuItemClickListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$OnMenuItemClickListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat { void setOnInflateListener(android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat$OnInflateListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat$OnInflateListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient { com.google.android.gms.internal.zzav zza(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.common.zza); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.common.zza'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil { android.app.Dialog zza(int,android.app.Activity,android.support.v4.app.Fragment,int,android.content.DialogInterface$OnCancelListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil { boolean showErrorDialogFragment(int,android.app.Activity,android.support.v4.app.Fragment,int,android.content.DialogInterface$OnCancelListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'io.realm.internal.CheckedRow { void nativeSetMixed(long,long,io.realm.internal.Mixed); }', but not the descriptor class 'io.realm.internal.Mixed'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'io.realm.internal.Table { void nativeUpdateFromSpec(long,io.realm.internal.TableSpec); }', but not the descriptor class 'io.realm.internal.TableSpec'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'io.realm.internal.Table { void nativeSetMixed(long,long,long,io.realm.internal.Mixed); }', but not the descriptor class 'io.realm.internal.Mixed'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'io.realm.internal.TableView { void nativeSetMixed(long,long,long,io.realm.internal.Mixed); }', but not the descriptor class 'io.realm.internal.Mixed'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'io.realm.internal.UncheckedRow { void nativeSetMixed(long,long,io.realm.internal.Mixed); }', but not the descriptor class 'io.realm.internal.Mixed'
Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 36 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 5 classes trying to access enclosing classes using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the inner classes attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 2 classes trying to access enclosing methods using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the enclosing method attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 33 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 11 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 2 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
Note: there were 7 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
Warning:there were 1798 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.957 secs
Information:1 error
Information:786 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

This list is only a part of the full log. I've tried the `-dontwarn` solution, but it didn't work. After it I've tried to `-keep` all the libraries, but it didn't work. Here's a list of what libraries I am using in the project:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:androidpagecontrol:0.1.1'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.84.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of proguard. Look up the libraries you use and check if they have a "Proguard" section mentioned at their implementation and copy that part of the code in your proguard file thats used at release build. For example Retrofit has 4 lines at the bottom of http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: ideally you should test your app in Release mode after adding every library, just to make sure it works as it can save you a lot of time later. Collecting all proguard things might take a while now

Comment: Yes, it does. I wasn't aware of this sadly (should I tell I am just a junior dev? :D ).

Comment: every developer has to go through it :)

Comment: A plugin for that would be very very very appreciated